# How to draw multiple routes on iOS 6 maps

Tags: iphone, polyline, ios6-maps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Multiple MKPolyline on MKMapView iOS6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13580664/multiple-mkpolyline-on-mkmapview-ios6)

I have two csv files containing latitude and longitude. I want to draw two polylines or routes on the iOS 6 maps. How can I do this??

I've tried the following code to draw single polyline.

```
NSString* filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"route" ofType:@"csv"];
NSString* fileContents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
NSArray* pointStrings = [fileContents componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

NSMutableArray* points = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:pointStrings.count];

for(int idx = 0; idx < pointStrings.count; idx++)
{
    // break the string down even further to latitude and longitude fields.
    NSString* currentPointString = [pointStrings objectAtIndex:idx];
    NSArray* latLonArr = [currentPointString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@","]];

    CLLocationDegrees latitude  = [[latLonArr objectAtIndex:0] doubleValue];
    CLLocationDegrees longitude = [[latLonArr objectAtIndex:1] doubleValue];

    CLLocation* currentLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:latitude longitude:longitude];
    [points addObject:currentLocation];
}

// create our route layer view, and initialize it with the map on which it will be rendered.
_routeView = [[CSMapRouteLayerView alloc] initWithRoute:points mapView:mapView];
```

but the problem with this code is that I can't scroll the map also double click to zoom in won't work (basically map freezes). Though it was working fine in Xcode 4.3 (with google maps).

Answer (score 0):

Don't use CSMapRouteLayerView, but use the mapview itself. You can easily draw custom paths right on the mapView.

See the MKMapKit Reference:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MapKit_Framework_Reference/_index.html

**Create Overlays with the following classes:**
`MKOverlayPathView` or
`MKPolylineView` and `MKPolyline` for lines.
(And if you want `MKPolygonView` and `MKPolygon for polygons.)

To use these classes with the mapView, use the following methods / delegate:

**MKMapView : Adding Overlays to the Map**
`– addOverlay:`

**MKMapViewDelegate: Managing Overlay Views**
`– mapView:viewForOverlay:`
`– mapView:didAddOverlayViews:`