# Multiple MKPolyline on MKMapView iOS6

Tags: ios, mkmapview, polyline

I am working with `MKMapView` to draw route using `MKPolyline`, I am able to draw single route with an array of waypoints.Now I want to draw multiple `MKPolyline`s on the `MKMapView` for instance,  A blue `MKPolyline` from `28.102021, 77.10129` to `28.20320, 77.3021` and A red `MKPolyline` from `28.50930, 77.89192` to `28.60291, 77.87328`. How can I achieve this ?

**Code:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = 6.0;
locationManager.distanceFilter = 1.0;
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
locationManager.delegate = self;
map.delegate = self;
[map setShowsUserLocation:YES];
[map setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeFollow animated:YES];
wayPoints = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:30];
newWayPoints = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:10];
totalDistance = 0.0;

stopTime = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:100];
startTime = [NSDate date];

SEL sel = @selector(timerTargetMethod);
NSInvocation* inv = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:
                     [self methodSignatureForSelector:sel]];
[inv setTarget:self];
[inv setSelector:sel];

stopTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5 invocation:inv repeats:true];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
[super viewDidUnload];
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
// e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}



- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation 
{
if(newLocation != nil && oldLocation != newLocation)
{
    tempNewLocation = newLocation;
    tempOldLocation = oldLocation;

}

}


- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mv didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views
{    
MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [views objectAtIndex:0];
id<MKAnnotation> mp = [annotationView annotation];
MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance([mp coordinate] ,4000,4000);

[mv setRegion:region animated:YES];
}

// MKMapViewDelegate
- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay
{
MKOverlayView* overlayView = nil;
MKPolylineView  * routeLineView = [[MKPolylineView alloc] initWithPolyline:self.routeLine];
routeLineView.fillColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0-1.0 green:0.0-1.0 blue:0.0-1.0 alpha:1.0f];
routeLineView.strokeColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0-1.0 green:0.0-1.0 blue:0.0-1.0 alpha:1.0f];

routeLineView.lineWidth = 3;
routeLineView.lineCap = kCGLineCapSquare;
overlayView = routeLineView;
return overlayView;

}

//define the targetmethod
-(void) timerTargetMethod 
{

if([[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:startTime] >= 100)
{
    [stopTimer invalidate];
    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
    NSLog(@"Time started at %@", startTime);
    NSLog(@"Time up at %@", stopTime);
}
else if (tempOldLocation.coordinate.latitude == tempNewLocation.coordinate.latitude   && tempNewLocation.coordinate.longitude == tempOldLocation.coordinate.longitude) 
{
    NSLog(@" Fix location found ");
}
else if( [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:startTime] >= 19 )
{
    if(roundf([[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:startTime]) == 20)
    {
        NSLog(@"First Time Location Update");
        latitudeLongitude.text = [[ NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%g , %g", tempNewLocation.coordinate.latitude, tempNewLocation.coordinate.longitude];

        float interval = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:startTime];
        int okInterval = roundf(interval);
        NSLog(@"Interval 1 , %d", okInterval );
        time.text = [[ NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d", okInterval  - 20];
        speed.text = @"0";
        totalDistance =  0;
        distance.text = @"0 meters";
    }
    else
    {
        latitudeLongitude.text = [[ NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%g , %g", tempNewLocation.coordinate.latitude, tempNewLocation.coordinate.longitude];

        float interval = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:startTime];
        int okInterval = roundf(interval);
        time.text = [[ NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d", okInterval  - 20];
        NSLog(@"Interval 2 , %d , %f", okInterval , interval);
        if((tempNewLocation.coordinate.latitude == tempOldLocation.coordinate.latitude && tempNewLocation.coordinate.longitude == tempOldLocation.coordinate.longitude) || tempNewLocation.speed < 0)
            speed.text = @"0";
        else
            speed.text = [[ NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%g meters/sec", tempNewLocation.speed];

        if(tempNewLocation.coordinate.latitude == tempOldLocation.coordinate.latitude && tempNewLocation.coordinate.longitude == tempOldLocation.coordinate.longitude)
        {

        }
        else if ([tempNewLocation distanceFromLocation:tempOldLocation] - tempNewLocation.horizontalAccuracy >= 0) 
            totalDistance +=  [tempNewLocation distanceFromLocation:tempOldLocation] - (tempNewLocation.horizontalAccuracy / 2);
        else
            totalDistance +=  [tempNewLocation distanceFromLocation:tempOldLocation];

        if (totalDistance < 0) 
            distance.text = @"0 meters";
        else
            distance.text = [[ NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%g meters", totalDistance];
    }


    [wayPoints addObject:tempNewLocation];
    MKMapPoint * pointsArray =
    malloc(sizeof(CLLocationCoordinate2D)*2);

    pointsArray[0]= MKMapPointForCoordinate(tempOldLocation.coordinate); 
    pointsArray[1]= MKMapPointForCoordinate(tempNewLocation.coordinate);

    routeLine = [MKPolyline polylineWithPoints:pointsArray count:2];
    free(pointsArray);

    if (tempNewLocation.coordinate.latitude - tempOldLocation.coordinate.latitude < 1) {
        [map addOverlay:routeLine];

    }
}
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Even if you don't use my answer below there are a couple of things you should take on board. In `viewForOverlay` you are ignoring the overlay that is given as a parameter and using the class variable `routeLine`.  If you ever hope to have two overlays on your map you need to be returning a view based on the the one the map is asking for. Also, what is this "0.0-1.0" stuff? Just use "-1" or a premade colour like `[UIColor whiteColor]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a lot of code you've shown there, the only bit that is relevant is `viewForOverlay`. In there you are given an object that conforms to the `MKOverlay` protocol and if you have created your own class to implement that you could add a variable that could be used to identify which overlay you were dealing with at that point and thus adjust your colours. Further down your code I see you are creating `MKPolyline`s, those are the overlays passed in to `viewForOverlay` and because they inherit from `MKShape` they have `title` and `subTitle` attributes you can use.

So when you create the `MKPolyline` you could set the `title`, maybe to "typeA" and "typeB", then in `viewForOverlay` you need to cast the overlay to a MKPolyline and check which title it has to decide which colour to use:

```
- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay
{
    if([overlay class] == MKPolyline.class)
    {
        MKOverlayView* overlayView = nil;
        MKPolyline* polyline = (MKPolyline *)overlay;
        MKPolylineView  * routeLineView = [[MKPolylineView alloc] initWithPolyline:polyline];
        if([polyline.title isEqualToString:@"typeA"])
        {
            routeLineView.fillColor = [UIColor redColor];
            routeLineView.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor];
        } else {
            routeLineView.fillColor = [UIColor blueColor];
            routeLineView.strokeColor = [UIColor blueColor];

        }
        routeLineView.lineWidth = 3;
        routeLineView.lineCap = kCGLineCapSquare;
        overlayView = routeLineView;
        return overlayView;
    } else {
        return nil;
    }
}
```

Comment: just one more question, I am able to add 2 `MKPolyline`s and if I add third just like I added the second it doesn't show up. is there a limit of how many `MKPolyline`s we can add ?

Comment: If there is a limit it is not 2, more likely in the dozens or hundreds. You've probably mixed up your variables and made two have the same coordinates or put one out of the current map view. Post another question with some code if you can't solve it.

Comment: thanks Craig, issue is resolved. I was using the same co-ordinates for 2 `MKPolyline`s.

Comment: @Craig: Sorry, I don’t know how to contact you otherwise: In an answer to SO <http://stackoverflow.com/a/16167959/1987726>, I once referred to a tutorial on how to add a polyline to a mapView. The link <http://spitzkoff.com/craig/?p=136> is now broken. I assume this was a tutorial written by you. Can it be found elsewhere, so that I could update my answer?

Comment: @Reinhard I don't recall writing a tutorial on that subject, and I've no connection to spitzkoff.com so I'm afraid I can't help you.

Comment: @Craig: Thanks anyway for your answer!